face recognition using hybrid deep learning algorithms
code in python how to get confusion matrix if we have 'Accuracy': 0.812, 'Precision': 0.902247191011236, 'Sensitivity_recall': 0.8882743362831859, 'Specificity': 0.09375, 'F1_score': 0.8952062430323299
need output of confusion matrix if we have 450000 dataset of human faces by applying 3 algorithms i.e. MTCNN,ArcFace and FaceNet
